# What are the text-mining packages for R and are there other open source text-mining programs?

Tags: r, text-mining

Can you recommend a text mining package in R that can be used against large volumes of data?
Secondly, is there a GUI available for any of the text mining packages in R?
Thirdly, is there another open source text mining program that is easy and intuitive to use?

Comment: @mbq: well, "is there an open source text mining package with a GUI?" would probably cover all three questions pretty well, it kind of already is one question...

Answer (score 18):

Please see the [CRAN Task View on Natural Language Processing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) which includes, among others, the [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tm) package already mentioned by Josh.

Answer (score 4):

See the [tm package](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/) and [this presentation](http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2010/Theussl+Feinerer+Hornik.pdf) by [Stefan Theussl](http://statmath.wu-wien.ac.at/~theussl/) given at the 2010 [R/Finance conference](http://www.rinfinance.com).

Answer (score 4):

Here are two further integrated projects:

- Python [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) (easy installation, good documentation)
- Java [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) (no experience with it, but looks promising; included in the link given by @Nick)

Both are open-source software.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, RapidMiner with the text mining extension.

There are many videos that show how it is done.

Comment: here is a 5-part video series: http://vancouverdata.blogspot.com/2010/11/text-analytics-with-rapidminer-loading.html

Answer (score 1):

GATE is very comprehensive.  It also allows you to work with different languages and has an ontology editor.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew McCallum (UMass) has a few NLP related software projects available on his [webpage](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/code.html). These are all in Java (I think) with source code available.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [CRAN Task View on Natural Language Processing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) mentioned by
Dirk, there are [quanteda package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda/index.html) and [NLP package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLP/index.html).