# Examples of text mining with R (tm package)

Tags: r, text-mining

I spent three days dabbling with `tm` after reading a draft paper by a friend where he explored a text corpus with UCINET, showing text clouds, two-mode network graphs and Single Value Decomposition (with graphics, using Stata). I ran under a large number of issues: on Mac OS X, there are issues with the Java behind libraries like Snowball (stemming) or Rgraphviz (graphs).

Could someone point out [not packages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/what-are-the-text-mining-packages-for-r-and-are-there-other-open-source-text-mini) – I have looked at `tm`, `wordfish` and `wordscores`, and know about NLTK – but **research, if possible with code, on textual data, that successfully uses `tm` or something else to analyse data like parliamentary debates or legislative documents?** I cannot seem to find much on the issue, and even less code to learn from.

My own project is a two-month parliamentary debate, with these variables informed in a CSV file: parliamentary session, speaker, parliamentary group, text of oral intervention. I am looking for divergence between speakers and especially between parliamentary groups in the use of rare and less rare terms, e.g. "security talk" against "civil liberties" talk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070483/text-retrieval-using-r

Answer (score 8):

The PhD Dissertation from the Author of tm, Ingo Feinerer from Austria, is written in the English language. Chapters 7-10 of this document contain applications of the tm package, with increasing complexity.

http://epub.wu.ac.at/1923/

> Chapter 7 presents an application of tm by analyzing the R-devel 2006
>   mailing list. Chapter 8 shows an application of text mining for
>   business to consumer electronic commerce. **Chapter 9 is an application
>   of tm to investigate Austrian supreme administrative court
>   jurisdictions concerning dues and taxes. [...]**. Chapter 10
>   shows an application for stylometry and authorship attribution on the
>   Wizard of Oz data set.

Read the whole document cover to cover. Note, however, that the document was written in 2008, and since then there have been a few API changes, for instance, the PhD thesis mentions a function `tmMap()` that has been renamed to `tm_map()`. So the code examples won't work as-is, you cannot use cut-and-paste to try them.

You can also go to

http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/users.html

> "In an attempt to inform new users about existing tm applications this
>   site aims to provide (an incomplete alphabetical) list of tm users and
>   their comments. Known users range from research institutes over
>   companies to individuals. "

and search on that page for the phrase "wrote a paper" and you'll find many links. I've read only one of the papers, "automatic topic detection in song lyrics". Quite interesting, and funny.

Comment: I think Feinerer's dissertation is the document that has helped me most so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A good place to start might be the [list of publications](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/publications.html) at the website for `tm`, such as this one:

- Text Mining Infrastructure in R. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05

The references list at the end of each of these publications includes successful applications of `tm`, which is what you seem to be looking for. There are many -- especially if you then follow the references of the references.

For example, Here's one that might be of relevance:

> Feinerer I, Hornik K (2007). \Text Mining of Supreme Administrative Court Jurisdictions."
>   In C Preisach, H Burkhardt, L Schmidt-Thieme, R Decker (eds.), \Data Analysis, Machine
>   Learning, and Applications (Proceedings of the 31st Annual Conference of the Gesellschaft
>   f ur Klassikation e.V., March 7{9, 2007, Freiburg, Germany)," Studies in Classication,
>   Data Analysis, and Knowledge Organization. Springer-Verlag.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the references. The level of detail is however insufficient in these publications -- I had to read from Feinerer's dissertation to get enough details on how to operate `tm` on my end. Still, thanks very much :)